# Rails: How to check which form in a view was submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are 2 forms on one page. I want an if else statement in the controller to use different params and variable values depending on which form was submitted. From doing a google search the best I came across was to have a value on the submit button.

```
 <%= f.submit "Save" :value => "x"  %>
```

If this is a plausible way I cant find how to make an if else statement for checking if the submit value is 'x'.

Something like

```
 if submit.value == 'x' 
    do something
 else
    do something else
 end
```

Really not sure. If there is another way of having an if else statement in the controller to catch witch form was submitted by using an id or name or whatever I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: If you need to use different params/variable values/etc... why don't you just create two separate controller actions, with two separate routes, and direct each form to their respective actions?

Comment: @SunnyK one controller takes the category id from params :category_id and then other controller takes it from params :id. when the info is passed to the one that takes it as params :category_id it cant find the paramater because it is stored in params :id changing the routes or params would break too much coding so this is a fast easy solution to a small problem I don't want to be spending much time on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***value*** of the ***submit button*** can be accessed with the help of `params[:commit]`, so you can use it to check which form is submitted.

```
if params[:commit] == 'x' 
    do something
 else
    do something else
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Pavan` has the direct answer, however if you're evaluating form submissions by their respective `submit` values, you've got a major issue with your pattern.

---

**Form**

Forms should be a way to pass values to your controller, which will then populate the model. You should not have to determine actions based on those values, unless you have different functionality...

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <%= form_for post do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The above will create multiple forms, all submitting to the `posts#update` method:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
      @post.update post_params
   end

   private

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

The *values* inside those forms don't matter, nor to which `post` object they were sent; they will all be evaluated in exactly the same way.

--

**Actions**

The other way around this is to make separate actions for the different forms:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   patch :update_2, on: :member
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def update_2
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
      @post.param = "value"
      @post.update post_params
   end
end

#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @post, url: posts_update_2_path(@post) do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would use 2 controllers but one form is for items and the other for categories. Category has many items and im using a category view so if i pass the item form to the items controller it wants the params :category_id for the category id but the category id is in params :id. my crappy nested resource has caused this issue. but I'm not really fussed with just passing them both to one controller and doing an if else statement, the data ends up being submitting and its faster than changing the parmas or routes around causing other things to break. And I'm the only one to read that coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
<%=f.submit "Basic update", name: "basic-update" %>
<%=f.submit "Security update", name: "security-update" %>
```

and then check in your controller:

```
if params.has_key? "security-update"
  #do something
elsif params.has_key? "basic-update"
  #do another thing
end
```

Comment: @Pavan Are you sure ?? It's working for me, test it and tell me.